# How to generate cost explorer by IAM user in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing

I have an AWS account with n number of IAM users. Each user will have access only to a specific list of services based on their role. Now I need to analyze the billing by each IAM user. This will provide the detailed view of each user for further cost optimization and other analysis.

But the AWS billing dashboard shows only the overall costs of that account. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: If you can educate the team to use a custom tag: "Owner => $User" and you enabled this tag in the billing settings - you can filter it by the "Owner" tag - It's quite simple if you're using Terraform to create such methodology. Ofcourse it'll only monitor the taggable services, but you'll get a good estimation on it (you can divide DT cost per resource and use the average)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Billing details per IAM entities or which IAM user has spent how much is NOT possible. Also, resources are owned by the account itself (not the user who creates it) and IAM users/roles/groups are not for billing purpose.

If you wish to analyze costs of different persons, then you can consider creating (or inviting) multiple accounts in [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/).

Comment: Is this still the case? How does  IAM entity get tracked with AwS organisations?